# Disable Ext Gwt "formdata" border

Tags: java, gwt, gxt

I have a formdata that I'm adding to a FormPanel. I'm adding few text fields to the formpanel with formdata. And then I'm adding the buttons to the Form panel. I only want the border around the Formpanel ie around text fields and buttons together. But currently I'm having a border around the formdata and another around the formpanel, separating the text fields and the buttons. 
Code is

```
private FormPanel editFormPanel = new FormPanel();
FormData formData = new FormData("-10");        
    formData.setMargins((new Margins(5)));  

event.setFieldLabel(EventDescription());
    event.setAllowBlank(false);
    event.setId(FORM_EVENT);

knownIssues.setFieldLabel(KnownIssues());
    knownIssues.setAllowBlank(false);
    knownIssues.setId(FORM_KNOWN_ISSUES);

editFormPanel.setButtonAlign(HorizontalAlignment.CENTER);

editFormPanel.add(event, formData);
editFormPanel.add(knownIssues, formData);

editFormPanel.addButton(btnAddLocation);
```

Is there a way that I can remove/disable the borders around the formdata?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I find a typo in your code:

```
    editnoccEventFormPanel.add(knownIssues, formData);
```

Is it another form panel?

FormData does not render border. Refer GXT examples in sencha.com. Here is the [link](http://www.sencha.com/examples/explorer.html)

Comment: Sorry, that was by mistake. I'm adding all the components to the same formpanel. I agree that Formdata does not have Border, hence I'm confused why I'm getting the border around the text fields only and one around the text fields after the buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution, need the setBodyBorder property of the FormPanel to false and that will solve the issue.

Thanks